# Creating a new table in power bi from existing table. Is using dax or query editor more efficient?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have several tables that contain the same field (Ex. Business Unit).  I am creating a separate table that contains all the Business Units that appear in the each of tables.  Then creating a relationships to have a global filter. I want to know the most efficient way to do this.

I can do this using Dax

```
Filter Cost Center = DISTINCT(
FILTER(
UNION(

      SUMMARIZE('Request Detail','Request Detail'[Business Unit]),
      SUMMARIZE('Assignment Detail', 'Assignment Detail'[Assignment Business Unit]),
      SUMMARIZE('Spend Detail','Spend Detail'[Assignment Business Unit])),
    not ISBLANK('Request Detail'[Business Unit])

)
```

or in the power query editor.

```
let Source = #"Assignment Detail",
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Assignment Business Unit"}),
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Duplicates", #"Request Detail"}),
#"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Appended Query",{"Assignment Business Unit", "Business Unit"}),
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Other Columns1", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
#"Removed Duplicates1" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Duplicates1",{{"Value", "Business Unit"}})
in #"Renamed Columns"
```

Is one way more  efficient than the other and why? Is there a scenario where I would use one vs. the other? Keep in mind I may have to do this multiple times for multiple dashboards.